# non-trivial locus of  a holomorphic vector bundle

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a holomorphic vector bundle over $Y$ (where $Y$ is an arbitrary complex manifold, not necessary projective). Does there exist an analytic subset $Z$ of $Y$ such that the restriction of $X$ to $Y \setminus Z$ is a trivial vector bundle?

Comment: If $Y$ is a projective variety, this follows from GAGA.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, I was wondering about the general case (which I have now made explicit).

Comment: This is also true for Stein manifolds.This follows from corollary 5.6.3
page 149 Hormander Introduction to several complex variables 3edn.

Comment: Mohan, this is very nice, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dima:A sufficient condition is global generation at some point of Y upto a twist by a holomorphic line bundle i.e a version of Cartan_Serre theorem A .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your manifold is complex projective, then the answer is yes. Otherwise it is no. You can take a $K3$ surface without complex curves and just consider its tangent bundle. Of curse it will stay *holomorphically* non-trivial, if you throw away finite number of points from $K3$, since any holomorphic vector field on a $K3$ surface defined outside a finite set is zero.

On the other hand, I guess, in this example the bundle is topoligcally trivial, since its first Chern class is zero.

**Added.** Let me sketch the proof of the statement, everything holds for compact complex aglebraic manifold. First every such a manifold admits a blow up that is projective. Pull back the complex bundle to the blow up. Then we get a holomorphic bundle over a complex projective manifold and such a bundle is algebraic. Hence it has meromorphic sections. Moreover we can chose meromorphic sections that a linearly independent at one point. It is clear that they trivialise the bundle over a complement to a complex analytic manifold.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you think of a class of non-projective manifolds for which the statement holds?

Comment: You can take any complex algebraic manifold, since such a manifold contains open affine submanifiold. But I would be surprised is something more general could be said. General complex manifolds are too wild (I would say)...

Comment: So the statement holds for an affine manifold? Why?

Comment: I don't think that the tangent bundle of a $K3$ surface is topologically trivial. Indeed the second Chern class of $X$ is never zero, otherwise $X$ would be a finite étale quotient of a complex torus.

Comment: Simone, you are right, it is not topologically trivial on K3 but it becomes topologically trivial once we throw away points, I believe

Comment: Dmitri, thank you for the update. You have hinted in your last comment that the statement is true for an affine algebraic manifold. Is it so? (I might have misinterpreted your comment)

Comment: Dima, Mohan gave a reference for the statement that what you want holds even for Stein varieties

Comment: Jörg Winkelmann proved that every compact complex manifold admits a non-trivial vector bundle <http://homepage.rub.de/Joerg.Winkelmann/publ/papers/banica.html>, so any complex manifold without codimension 1 analytic subspaces would give a counterexample.

Comment: I cannot find anymore a comment by Dmitri where he was asking me if holomorphic vector bundles on Stein manifolds are trivial. The answer is no in general. Anyway a famous theorem of Grauert says that the holomorphic and the topological classifications of complex vector bundles on a Stein manifold are the same. Quite often (for instance if the manifold is contractible or if it is an open Riemann Surface) this implies that every holomorphic vector bundle is holomorphically trivial.

Comment: On the other hand, how do you show that the tangent bundle of a K3 becomes topologically trivial once you remove a finite number of points?

Comment: Simone, just take a (smooth) section of tangent bundle that vanishes in finite number of points. Throw away this points, and take a complex sub-bundle of the tangent space, orthogonal to the section. It has c_1=0 and hence is trivial.